# Como fazer uma pesquisa por CEP no VB

Tags: c#, visual-basic-6, cep, código-postal

Como que faço para coletar dados de endereço(Logradouro, Cidade, Bairro, Rua) de um site, referente ao Cep de entrada usando `VB`?

Tenho um código parecido em `C#`

Vejo duas alternativas:

1. Traduzir o código para `VB`
2. Executar o código do `c#` a partir do `VB` para encontrar o endereço e coletar os resultados, armazenando-os em `textboxes` do formulário de preenchimento de endereço no `VB`, para visualização instantânea (não sei se é possível)

Alguém poderia ajudar com algumas dessas alternativas acima.

Código em `C#`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string xml = "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.phpcep=@cep&formato=xml"
           .Replace("@cep",maskedTextBox1.Text); 

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.ReadXml(xml);

        label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
        label3.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();

        textBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
        textBox4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
        textBox5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque deste o using System dentro de todo código, formatando de maneira ideal

Comment: Deu certo a conversão ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Convertendo C# para VB.NET

```
Dim xml As String = String.Format("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep={0}&formato=xml", maskedTextBox1.Text)
    
Dim ds As New DataSet()
ds.ReadXml(xml)
    
label1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1).ToString()
label3.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(5).ToString()
    
textBox2.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(6).ToString()
textBox3.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(4).ToString()
textBox4.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3).ToString()
textBox5.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(2).ToString()
```

**Mudanças:**

- Para declarar variável utilizado [Dim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx);
- Trocar [] por ();
- Para formatar a String Url foi utilizado [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou! heheheheh apesar de ter algumas coisas que achei simples de traduzir, como definição de variável e atribuição de valor as textboxes... não fazia ideia de como ficaria a parte da busca no banco de dados do site... o {0} no lugar do @. Muito útil, funcionou bonitinho!

Comment: @user7854, aqui tem a explicação do String.Format do próprio site microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ola, eu faço assim:

Aqui tem o [webservice](http://www.byjg.com.br/site/webservice.php/ws/cep?WSDL) se cadastra [ByJG](http://www.byjg.com.br/) é gratuito!

Depois de adicionar a referencia, como eu utilizo em varios formularios criei no Modulo uma variável global e a função que recebe os parametros:

```
 Public CepResultBusca
```

Essa é a função:

```
 Public Sub BuscarCep(cep As String)
    Dim connWebCep As New br.com.byjg.www.CEPService

    //verificação simples apenas para saber se o campo cep esta preenchido
    If Trim(cep) = Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    //no meu caso faço a busca apenas por numero do cep, que é passado por parametro
    //.obterLogradouroAuth vai da sua necessidade!
    CepResultBusca = connWebCep.obterLogradouroAuth(cep, "login", "senha")
End Sub
```

crie no evento KeyDown do TextBox cep o tratamento para o resultado da busca, se preferir pode fazer direto no modulo e devolver já formatado:

```
 Private Sub cep_cobranca_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles cobranca_cep.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
        BuscarCep(cobranca_cep.Text)
        Dim r As String = CepResultBusca
        Trim(r)
        Try
            Dim rua = Split(r, ",")(0)
            Dim bairro = Split(r, ",")(1)
            Dim cidade = Split(r, ",")(2)
            Dim uf = Split(r, ",")(3)
            cobranca_endereco.Text = Trim(rua)
            cobranca_bairro.Text = Trim(bairro)
            cobranca_cidade.Text = Trim(cidade)
            cobranca_uf.Text = Trim(uf)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(r)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

o caso o cep não seja encontrado o webservice retorna uma menssagem que tratei no exception do try cath com exit sub para sair aqui:

```
 MsgBox(r)
 Exit Sub
```